# Populating values in text box on the selection changed event of Combo Box?

Tags: wpf, vb.net-2010

I have a wpf application which has combo box and multiple text boxes.

On the window load event the combo box is filled with the Employee IDs. When I select any ID then the below text boxes should display the name, city, zip, country of the selected "Id".
 I did wrote the below code for filling in the values in text boxes.
    Private Sub dataview1(ByVal GUID As String)
        Try

```
        Dim viewDs As New DataSet()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "Select * from tblEmployeeInfo Where ID = '" & GUID.Trim & "'"
        viewDs = GetData(Query, True)

        Dim dv As DataView = New DataView(viewDs.Tables(0))
        Dim Notify As String = String.Empty
        If dv.Count > 0 Then

            If Not IsDBNull(dv(0)("ID")) Then
                txtGUID.Text = dv(0)("ID")
            Else
                txtGUID.Text = String.Empty
            End If

           If Not IsDBNull(dv(0)("StreetName"))     Then
                txtStName.Text = dv(0)("StreetName")
            Else
                txtStName.Text = String.Empty
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("No Values Found")
    End Try
End Sub
```

And called the above function on Selection Changed Event of Combo Box as below:

```
Private Sub ID CB_SelectionChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles IDCB.SelectionChanged
    StreetCB.IsEnabled = False
   DataView1(IDCB.SelectedItem)
```

Though it hits the ViewMode Function but it never populates any values in my text boxes.

Am I missing any thing in it?

Is there any way I could achieve?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Though it hits the ViewMode Function but it never populates any values in my text boxes.

Step through this in the debugger.  This could happen if your query returns no results, which is, I suspect, the issue in this case.